# using a method return in java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

I am new to java and programming overall, so please bear with me. In the code below,when I run object.ValidateGuess(), I am propted 3 times "Please enter a letter to be guessed:". Why is that? Is it because I use the GetGuess() method in the if statement?? I want to use the return of that method only, not for it to run every time.
thanks in advances

```
public char GetGuess(){
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to be guessed");
    Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
    return guess.nextLine().charAt(0);
}

public boolean ValidateGuess(){
    boolean isHit = false;
    int triesLeft = MAX_TRIES;
    if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(GetGuess()) < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Your guess was incorrect");
        triesLeft -= 1;
        System.out.println(triesLeft);
        mMisses += GetGuess();
    } else if (GetGuess() == (int)GetGuess()) {
        System.out.println("you have to input a letter!!!");
    } else {
        mHits += GetGuess();
        isHit = true;
    }
```

Comment: Then put the return value in a variable and have the `if` condition involve that variable rather than call the method itself. A method call is exactly that: it calls the method.

Comment: Because the method is executed on both if conditions plus on the else when the other conditions do not meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if conditions you call every time `GetGuess` so the user has to make an input again and again. You have to save the value from `GetGuess` and work with that.

(Btw: it is better style to write method names not in capital letters at the beginning).

You can change your code into that:

```
public char GetGuess(){
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to be guessed");
    Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
    return guess.nextLine().charAt(0);
}

public boolean ValidateGuess(){
    boolean isHit = false;
    int triesLeft = MAX_TRIES;
    char guessValue = GetGuess(); //Here you store the guess and now you can work with that in your if conditions
    if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(guessValue) < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Your guess was incorrect");
        triesLeft -= 1;
        System.out.println(triesLeft);
        mMisses += guessValue;
    } else if (guessValue == (int)guessValue) {
        System.out.println("you have to input a letter!!!");
    } else {
        mHits += guessValue;
        isHit = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You call the method at multiple times,

```
if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(GetGuess()) < 0 ){
        [...]
        mMisses += GetGuess();
} else if (GetGuess() == (int)GetGuess()) {
        [...]
} else {
        mHits += GetGuess();
}
```

which means you are calling for a unique letter **multiple times**.

Remedy this by storing `GetGuess()` in a variable and readjusting:

```
char guess = GetGuess();
if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(guess) < 0 ){
        [...]
        mMisses += guess;
} else if (guess == (int)guess) {
        [...]
} else {
        mHits += guess;
}
```

If it helps, remember that every time you call a function, every single line is executed within that function **every time** regardless of how, where, when and why you are calling it. A method has one job, and that is to, literally, run through it's method.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. Try storing the value, instead of calling the function again and again.

```
public boolean ValidateGuess(){
    boolean isHit = false;
    int triesLeft = MAX_TRIES;
    char guess = GetGuess();
    if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(guess) < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Your guess was incorrect");
        triesLeft -= 1;
        System.out.println(triesLeft);
        mMisses += guess;
    } else if (guess == (int)guess) {
        System.out.println("you have to input a letter!!!");
    } else {
        mHits += guess;
        isHit = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should execute GetGuess() once and then store the result in a variable. In your following statements, you can then examine this variable:

```
char guessResult = GetGuess();
if (mCorrectAnswer.indexOf(guessResult) < 0){
    System.out.println("Your guess was incorrect");
    triesLeft -= 1;
    System.out.println(triesLeft);
    mMisses += guessResult;
} else if (guessResult == (int)guessResult) {
    System.out.println("you have to input a letter!!!");
} else {
    mHits += guessResult;
    isHit = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its because you are calling the method each time you put it in the if conditions. Try to store the return value of the method in a variable and use that variable instead.